# Color leak from multicols within a figure

Tags: floats, color, multicol

[image: colorleak page one]
[image: colorleak page two]

The text at the bottom of page 2 is red, despite the fact that the color change in the code below originates from `\color{red}\normalcolor` within the `multicols` within the `figure` and should naively not have had such an impact. No effect is seen if either:

1. one comments out the `\begin{multicols}` and `\end{multicols}` lines,
2. one comments out the `\begin{figure*}` and `\end{figure*}` lines.

My question is why does this happen? (I expect to hear about some kind of `whatsit` subtlety).

and is there a work-around ?  (in my context I have `\color{red}` and later `\normalcolor` before the text, more or less as here, and I can not change that, so the solution should not change anything to the inside of the `multicols` and the only customizing possibility would be to add extra stuff either before or after the multicols environment or both).

**Update** David's [proposal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138786/4686) to add a group or brace pair inside the `multicols` cures the problem (I initially thought I had no access to these contents, but I had forgotten my own hooks) and another way is to add `\normalcolor` or even `\color{green}` (sic) inside the `figure*` environment *before* the `multicols` environment. This second medicine avoids to have to insert anything inside the `multicols`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
% COLOR LEAK IF COLOR WITHIN MULTICOLS WITHIN FIGURE
\begin{document}
Hello World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World
World World World 
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \color{red}\normalcolor
    Hello. World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World\par
  \end{multicols}
\end{figure*}
World World World 
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World
World World World 
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World
World World World 
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World World World World World World World
World I AM RED, WHY?

\end{document}
```

Comment: forgot to say that the images were produced via `dvipng` but compilation via `pdflatex` gives the same output.

Comment: adding `\normalcolor` within `figure*` after `\end{multicols}` does not modify anything.

Comment: I say in the text that I have no easy access to the `multicols` contents, but I had forgotten my own hooks precisely designed for that. So I could solve my real life problem following David's advice and using the hooks to put the entire stuff from inside the `multicols` within a group _inside the_ `multicols`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

David's suspicion is correct: `multicol` is at fault here. When the environment detects that it is used inside a box (e.g., in a float in this case) it will collect its material inside a vertical box and then applies its balancing routine by splitt the box into columns. It does this by using `\setbox` in a way that is *not* "color safe".

As a result the first color change in the sequence `\color{red}\normalcolor`  (or more precisely the second last color change) will  be misinterpreted by the surrounding float environment as the outer color to be restored after the float as it remains on the "color stack".

A possible patch for this would look as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\mult@@cols}{\vbox\bgroup}{\vbox\bgroup\color@setgroup}{}{\PATCHerror}
\patchcmd{\endmulticols}{\egroup}{\color@endgroup\egroup}{}{\PATCHerror}
\makeatother
```

but obviously that should be properly integrated into the `multicol` package. A nice example of the fact that this part of the `multicol` code predates LaTeX2e and quite interesting that it took this bug 20 years to surface.

#### Update

Just for the record this patch has been integrated in multicol for a while so this problem should no longer happen.

Comment: `\PATCHerror`...?

Comment: @Werner, well if the patch fails for some reason it will execute \PATCHerror which his undefined ... ok I was a little lazy

Answer (score 10):

Interesting:-)

As it's an interaction between `color` and `multicol` then it's probably something to do with some code of mine or Frank's. Obviously I suspect Frank:-)

No time to debug now but such problems are usually fixed by adding an extra group, and adding `{}` as here, fixes it in this case.

```
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    {\color{red}\normalcolor
    Hello. World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World World
    World World World World World\par}
```

Comment: I had tried the group or braces to encapsulate `multicols` and that didn't work. Unfortunately I can't easily (I could with some effort) follow your tip in my real life case; the whole `\multicols` is created by some macro, and basically I can only prefix or postfix it ... so ... I'll wait before moving your rep closer to the 1M mark...

Comment: @jfbu Wouldn't `\begingroup...\endgroup` instead of `{...}` do it's job as well?

Comment: @tochecz David's fix can be applied indeed with `\begingroup...\endgroup`, the problem is that this is _inside_ the `multicols`. I do not have easy access to this, and as I said if I put the whole `multicols` with its contents inside a group or a brace pair, this doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: @tochecz Actually I had entirely forgotten in my real-life case that I have at my disposals hooks (this is my own package, I had prepared these hooks but rarely use them) to put things inside the `multicols` before and after its contents. Something like `\def\hookbefore{\begingroup}` and `\def\hookafter{\endgroup}` or with `\bgroup` and `\egroup` is a way to put David's proposal to work in my real life problem. This cured indeed the color leak. OK, so now the thing remaining is to understand the source of the problem!

Comment: @jfbu look for a discussion of "colo[u]r safety" in grfguide and color package documentation, which explains why extra groups are a good thing.

Comment: @jfbu use `\def\hookafter{\par\endgroup}` in case the content doesn't have an explicit `\par` or blank line at the end (otherwise things could go very wrong:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I will (again...). I knew about the difference between `\setbox` and `\sbox` in that regard, but I am uneasy with all things related with `\whatsit`'s

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok for `\par`; i my real life case it is already there.